# Reference request: Arithmetic circuit complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, arithmetic-circuits

I am completely new to this field. I want to read the prelims and unfortunately, I don't see any book written for a beginner in this area. Can anyone give me some basic starting points/references(text/video) for a gentle introduction? I found these two given below.

Determinant versus permanent by Manindra Agarwal https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6a05/a4fe63e409ba040b890bbf5da0f3b1ca7085.pdf

Arithmetic circuits by Amir Shpilka

[https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shpilka/publications/SY10.pdf](https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Eshpilka/publications/SY10.pdf)

***Is there any other material which can be more appropriate for a beginner?***

Comment: Vollmer's book has a section on arithmetic circuit complexity; that's fairly light.  Heribert Vollmer, "Introduction to Circuit Complexity".

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you want to do. For more structural questions there is a relatively recent survey by Meena Mahajan:

Meena Mahajan: Algebraic Complexity Classes.

There is also the book by Bürgisser:

Peter Bürgisser: Completeness and Reduction in Algebraic Complexity Theory.

For Geometric Complexity Theory, you might try the theses of [Joshua Grochow](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~jgrochow/grochow-thesis.pdf) or [Christian Ikenmeyer](http://digital.ub.uni-paderborn.de/ubpb/urn/urn:nbn:de:hbz:466:2-10472). I think both of them have introduction into the field, but I must admit that I have read neither of them.

Comment: Thanks but already checked these materials before,not the geometric one though.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the references already mentioned, you could check out

> Xi Chen, Neeraj Kayal and Avi Wigderson (2011), [Partial Derivatives in Arithmetic Complexity and Beyond](http://dx.doi.org/10.1561/0400000043), Foundations and Trends® in Theoretical Computer Science: Vol. 6: No. 1–2, pp 1-138. ([Freely available author's version](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/ChenKaWi2011.pdf))

Although the title makes it sound fairly specific, it's a pretty decent introduction.

I only know of one textbook devoted to this topic (Burgisser-Clausen-Shokrollahi "Algebraic Complexity Theory"), but it may not be the easiest introduction for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

Another good source that I am surprised hasn't been mentioned yet is the [survey](https://github.com/dasarpmar/lowerbounds-survey) by Ramprasad Saptharishi.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/106/104/106104221/) is course on Arithmetic Circuit Complexity, offered by Prof Nitin Saxena (the S of AKS primality test). The syllabus and pre-requisites can be found [here](https://onlinecourses.nptel.ac.in/noc20_cs47/preview).